# Merge the [delete] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

The tags [deletion](/questions/tagged/deletion), [deleting](/questions/tagged/deleting) and [deleted](/questions/tagged/deleted) are all states of the much more popular tag [delete](/questions/tagged/delete).

I suggest [deletion](/questions/tagged/deletion), [deleting](/questions/tagged/deleting) and [deleted](/questions/tagged/deleted) are all made synonyms of [delete](/questions/tagged/delete).

Answer (score 2):

perhaps [deletion](/questions/tagged/deletion), [deleting](/questions/tagged/deleting), and [deleted](/questions/tagged/deleted) are made synonyms of [deletion](/questions/tagged/deletion), but not of [delete](/questions/tagged/delete), as `delete` is an operator in many languages, including C++ and Javascript

Comment: If we do this which one should be the master tag?

Comment: I'm not sure. I thing [tag:deletion] would be best, but another one would work

Comment: I think the [delete] tag should continue to be used as is. If it is reserved only for the "delete" keyword or operator then it would be a lot of work to clean it up and it would only continue to be misused. If a question references a specific "delete" keyword then it should use a specific tag such as [sql-delete]